# Inactive sequence in stacked sequence structure in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I have a stacked sequence structure with 6 sequences. My problem is when I run the program, after the first sequence, data which should flow to the second one does not pass through this sequence. I checked it by having two numeric indicators, one inside and the other outside the wall of this sequence. Do you have any idea about this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you could attach a screenshot of the sequences.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a more recent version of LabVIEW, the fastest way to check your data flow is to right click on the sequence structure, and select Replace>>Replace with Flat Sequence.

This will convert any sequence locals to wires, which makes debugging much easier.  You can use Undo to revert the structure back, if needed.

On a more general note, it's usually a good idea to avoid stacked sequences.  They're difficult to use well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jakub that we need a screenshot, but here's my attempt: you can either use a "Local Variable" or a Shift Register (I prefer the former unless you are using the variable in every sequence).

[image]